# CC.NET: howto trigger an extended build when a subdirectory in svn has changed

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

We have a couple of projects configured in cc.net. Each of these projects has following items in it's working directory (svn):

- source
- lib
- db scripts
- SSIS package(s)

We would like to know if there is a way to find out if there are any modifications in the subdirectory containing the SSIS packages? This would allow us to do a full build (including execution of package). We don't want to do this with every build since package execution might take some time...

Our other option is to create a cc.net project that does the complete builds at night time.

Does anybody have a nice solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SvnVersion task from MSBuild Community Tasks to identify the latest revision on the SSIS package subdirectory. Then compare it to one you've stored in a file somewhere in your working directory or elsewhere.

If it's different, pass a property to your main MSBuild task with a flag instructing to build and execute the SSIS packages. Once that's done, update your revision file with the new new revision number for the SSIS subdir.